# There are no registered paths for namespace "App". FosRestBundle, Symfony

Tags: api, symfony, twig, fosrestbundle

I receive such a message "There are no registered paths for namespace "App"" while doing a request to my API. I use FosUserBundle. FosRest tries to render the twig view all the time.

```
fos_rest:
param_fetcher_listener: true
body_listener: true
format_listener:
    rules:
      - { path: '^/api/test', priorities: ['json'], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: false }
      - { path: '^/', stop: true }
view:
    templating_formats:
        html: false
    default_engine: none
    view_response_listener: 'force'
    mime_types:
        json: ['application/json;charset=UTF-8', 'application/json']
routing_loader:
    default_format: json
disable_csrf_role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
```

and my ApiController:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Form\Type\PostThankYouFormType;
use AppBundle\Entity\PostThankYou;
use AppBundle\Entity\Company;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\View;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\Annotation\ApiDoc;

class ApiController extends FOSRestController
{
    /**
     * @Route(name="app.api.test", path="/api/test")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @View()
     * @return \FOS\RestBundle\View\View
     */
    public function getCompanyUsers(Request $request, Company $company)
    {
        return $this->view([
            'test' => 'test',
        ]);
    }
```

Error:

[image]

I tried all the ways found on stackoverflow but none of them worked. 
I just expect json response.

I found a mistake. I had two times write key "fos_rest" in my config.yml. First was in the middle of config and second in the end of file...

Comment: You should use fos rest route annotation instead of symfony one.

Comment: Have you tried replacing @Route & @Method with `FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Get` annotation?

Comment: Sure seem like you have at least one class defined somewhere with a namespace of App instead of AppBundle.  Maybe do a global search for it.

Comment: I found a mistake. I had two times write key "fos_rest" in my config.yml. First was in the middle of config and second in the end of file...

Comment: @wojoj Please post that as an answer. I just came here searching for a solution to the same exact issue and I almost missed your comment.

Answer (score 0):

To be a fully register action I think you should use Action in suffix e.g.:

```
public function getCompanyUsersAction(
```

Comment: Not any more but even if this was the problem then you would get a completely different error message.